# How to define @Value as nullable in spring with kotlin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I don't want autowiring fail when one specific property is missing. In that case i can accept nulls. How can i achieve it?

```
@Service
class MyClass(
        @Value("\${my.nullable.property}") property: String?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default when using `@Value` and set it to an expression that evaluates to null:

```
@Value("\${my.nullable.property:#{null}}")
```

Anything after the `:` is the default if `my.nullable.property` cannot be defined. Because putting `null` there would be treated as a `String`, we have to use an expression that evaluates to null, which is wrapped by `#{}`.

Comment: so there no kotlin nullability `?` support? it has to be done same way as in java?